# If $\sin{x}=t, \quad x\in(\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi),$ what is $\tan{x}?$

Tags: trigonometry

So, according to the interval in which $x$ lies, the value of the sine is negative, and positive for the cosine. Using trig identity I get that

$$\cos{x}=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2{x}}=\pm\sqrt{1-t^2}.$$

Knowing the signs of sine and cosine, I pick $\sqrt{1-t^2}$. Computing $\tan{x}$ I get

$$\tan{x}=\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}=\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2{x}}}=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}.$$

The pick answers are

a) $\frac{\sqrt{t^2}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}};$

b) $-\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}};$

c) $-\frac{|t|}{\sqrt{1-t^2}};$

d) None of the above.

Why is c) correct?

Comment: Hint : As easy as ...way .draw a unit circle and show an angle in $\in (\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi)$

Comment: I have, and I clearly stated above that sine is negative and cosine is positive in that range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You correctly found that 
$$\tan x = \frac{t}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}}$$
Observe that since $x \in (\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi)$, $t = \sin x < 0$.  Hence, $t = -|t|$.  Thus, 
$$\tan x = \frac{t}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}} = -\frac{|t|}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}}$$

Comment: Why not $t=-t?$

Comment: Notice that the only solution of the equation $t = -t$ is $t = 0$.  In this case, $t < 0$, so $|t| = -t > 0$.  Try substituting a specific value for $t$ such as $-1/2$ to see why $t = -|t|$.

Answer (score 0):

Both $\sin,\tan $ are negative in the given fourth quadrant. By taking absolute value and assigning a definite negative sign .. option (c) ensures/forces negative   sign to it.

Comment: Why doesn't just a negative sign force this?

Comment: As stated fourth quadrant $\sin,\tan $ are negative and just a negative sign goes positive that is wrong sign for the quadrant chosen.