# If $\cos{x}=t$ and $x\in (\pi/2, \pi)$, then $\tan{x}$ is?

Tags: calculus

The interval in which $x$ lies, forces us to only work in the second quadrant. For this quadrant it follows that $\sin{x}>0$ and $\cos{x}<0.$ So:

$$\sin{x}=\pm{\sqrt{1-\cos^2{x}}}=\pm\sqrt{1-t^2}.$$

Since we noted that $\sin{x}>0,$ I choose the positive value $\sin{x}=\sqrt{1-t^2}.$ Now $$\tan{x}=\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}=\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{t}.$$

But $t$ has to be negative since $\cos{x}<0$. So the answer should be $$\tan{x}=\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{-t},$$

but correct answer is $\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{t}.$ Why?

I had a [similar thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418079/if-sinx-t-quad-x-in-frac3-pi2-2-pi-what-is-tanx) a few days ago. The resoning in that one does not work on this problem despite them being of almost identical nature.

Comment: Because $\tan x$ is $\sin x/\cos x$, not $\sin x/(-\cos x)$.

Comment: $\tan x$ is also negative but in your answer it is positive while in the correct answer it is negative.

Comment: Seems like none of you checked the similar thread... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418079/if-sinx-t-quad-x-in-frac3-pi2-2-pi-what-is-tanx

Answer (score 3):

Hint ... $t$ itself is negative because of the interval for $x$

Comment: So how then do you explain this thread? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418079/if-sinx-t-quad-x-in-frac3-pi2-2-pi-what-is-tanx

Comment: Again, $t$ is negative because of the interval. They could have written just $t$ instead of $-|t|$

Comment: I don't understand. In this question, $t=-a$ for some $a\in[-1,1].$ The same applies for $t$ in the other question that I linked. But in this question, qe don't need to put a negative sign infront of $t$, but in the other question, we need to put $-|t|$ instead of $t$.

Comment: In both questions $t$ is negative.

Comment: I know, in both of my answers I state that $t<0.$ But still the answers differ. Why is the answer in the other thread $$\tan{x}=\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}?$$ Here, $t$ is also "already negative because of the interval". Why do we then replace $t$ with $-|t|$?

Comment: I agree it's not necessary, but it happens to be correct!

Comment: Why does it happen to be correct? if $t<0,$ then $-|-t|=-|t|.$ I really don't understand this.

Comment: @Parseval $|-a|=|a|$ is true independently of $a$ being positive or negative. If $t<0$, then $|t|=-t$, so $t=-|t|$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x\in\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right)$, we see that $\sin{x}>0$, which says that
$$\sin{x}=\sqrt{1-t^2}.$$
Thus, $$\tan{x}=\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{t}.$$